# iOS9 Swift File Creating NSFileManager.createDirectoryAtPath with NSURL

Tags: swift, ios9, nsfilemanager

Before iOS9, we had created a directory like so

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
let logsPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("logs")
let errorPointer = NSErrorPointer()
NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(logsPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: errorPointer)
```

But with iOS9 they removed String.stringByAppendingPathComponent. The auto convert tool replaced our use of String with NSURL. createDirectoryAtPath() takes a string so I need to convert the NSURL to a string. We used absolutePath like so: (update for iOS9)

```
let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
let logsPath = documentsPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent("logs")
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(logsPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Unable to create directory Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513
>   "You don’t have permission to save the file “logs” in the folder
>   “Documents”."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F2EF2D4F-94AF-4BF2-AF9E-D0ECBC8637E7/Documents/logs/,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x15664d070 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
>   "Operation not permitted"}}

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I figured this one out. createDirectoryAtPath() is unable to process a path with the "file://" prefix. To get a path without the prefix you must use path() or relativePath().

```
let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
let logsPath = documentsPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent("logs")
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(logsPath.path!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
}
```

Incorrect path (notice file://):

file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F2EF2D4F-94AF-4BF2-AF9E-D0ECBC8637E7/Documents/logs/

Correct path:

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F2EF2D4F-94AF-4BF2-AF9E-D0ECBC8637E7/Documents/logs/

Comment: **relativePath** is the winner. I had .absoluteString but seems like that is long since outdated.

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3**

```
let documentsPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
let logsPath = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("logs")
do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: logsPath!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

```swift
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let logsPath = paths[0].appendingPathComponent("logs")
do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: logsPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    NSLog("Unable to create directory \(error.debugDescription)")
}
```