# Error: You don’t have permission to save the file in the folder

Tags: ios, swift, ssziparchive

I've successfully downloaded the file but I am unable to save the file. Because I keep getting the error(s):

```
[SSZipArchive] Error: You don’t have permission to save the file “fileName” in the folder “Folder_Name”.
[SSZipArchive] Error: You don’t have permission to save the file “fileName” in the folder “__MACOSX”.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

### Code

**Unzip file function call**

```
 ZipManager.unzipFile(atPath: filePath, delegate: self)
```

**ZipManager.swift**

```
private static let documentsURL: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

static func unzipFile(atPath path: String, delegate: SSZipArchiveDelegate)
    {
        let destFolder = "/Folder_Name"
        let destPath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(destFolder, isDirectory: true)
        let destString = destPath.absoluteString
        
        if ( !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destString) )
        {
            try! FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: destPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        }
        
        SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: path, toDestination: destString, delegate: delegate)
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `destPath` to the `SSZipArchive.unzipFile` function?

Comment: @Kymer nope it takes in a `String` so I can't put in a `URL`

Comment: Well... `destString` then? Maybe you should clean-up that function a bit. It seems like you aren't using the `path` argument for example.

Comment: @Kymer not sure what you mean. I use `path` in ` SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: path, toDestination: destString, delegate: delegate)`

Comment: do you have app sandboxing turned on?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann nvm figured it out

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659869/ios9-swift-file-creating-nsfilemanager-createdirectoryatpath-with-nsurl) I realized its because of this line:

```
let destString = destPath.absoluteString
```

I had to change it to:

```
let destString = documentsURL.relativePath
```

Which allowed me to greatly simplify my function:

```
static func unzipFile(atPath path: String) -> Bool
    {
        let destString = documentsURL.relativePath

        let success: Void? = try? SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: path, toDestination: documentsURL.relativePath, overwrite: true, password: nil)

        if success == nil
        {
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
```