# Permissions to save file in the Documents folder on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, file-permissions

I have an issue with saving/replacing image files to the Documents folder in my app.

In the AppDelegate I have a two properties:

```
let documentsDirectory: URL = { return FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! }()
let defaultDirectory: URL = { return Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("DefaultBlocks.bundle", isDirectory: true) }()
```

It looks like the path is valid, have a log output:

> [Verbose] application(:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) > Docs URL:
>   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6ED04DA7-077F-4AE2-AB74-2EED02932823/Documents/
>
> [Verbose] application(:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) > Defaults URL: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/A11D6A4A-E108-483F-86EC-BBFA10E77F72/TheAwesomeApp.app/DefaultBlocks.bundle/

My app logic is: if user requested to reload default images, then replace images in the Documents folder with the reference copies from the app bundle.

I try to implement replacement in the code (called from **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**):

```
func ReloadDefaults() {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    do {
        let destDirURL = appDelegate.documentsDirectory
        let defaultURLs = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "png", subdirectory: "DefaultBlocks.bundle/_default_images_")

        for url in defaultURLs! {
            let destURL: URL = destDirURL.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
            log.verbose("Src URL: \(url)")
            log.verbose("Dest URL: \(destURL)")
            _ = try fileManager.replaceItemAt(destURL, withItemAt: url.absoluteURL)
        }
    }
    catch {
        log.error("File copy error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

> [Verbose] ReloadDefaults() > Src URL: image-512.png --
>   file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/A11D6A4A-E108-483F-86EC-BBFA10E77F72/TheAwesomeApp.app/DefaultBlocks.bundle/_default_images_/
>
> [Verbose] ReloadDefaults() > Dest URL:
>   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6ED04DA7-077F-4AE2-AB74-2EED02932823/Documents/image-512.png

Unfortunately I've got a error for the **replaceItemAt** call:

> [Error] ReloadDefaults() > File copy error: You don’t have permission
>   to save the file “image-512.png” in the folder “Documents”.

I have a recent versions of the Xcode and iOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS9 Swift File Creating NSFileManager.createDirectoryAtPath with NSURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659869/ios9-swift-file-creating-nsfilemanager-createdirectoryatpath-with-nsurl)

Comment: May be, but all **replaceItemAt** declarations have an URL as a parameter and I can not pass just path without "file://" prefix. So I did not know how to fix this.