# You don't have permission to save file in Mac Mojave

Tags: macos, file-manager, macos-mojave, swift4.2, macos-app-extension

In my macOS app I'm trying to create a directory using the below extension

```
extension URL {
    static func createFolder(folderName: String, folderPath:URL) -> URL? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let folderURL = folderPath.appendingPathComponent(folderName)
        // If folder URL does not exist, create it
        if !fileManager.fileExists(atPath: folderURL.path) {
            do {
                // Attempt to create folder
                // try fileManager.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                // try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: folderURL.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                try fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: folderURL.relativePath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription + ":\(folderURL.path)")
                return nil
            }
        }
        return folderURL
    }
}
```

When I invoke this call its giving me error

> You don’t have permission to save the file “FolderName” in the folder
>   “SelectedFolder”.:/Users/USERNAME/Workspace/SelectedFolder/FolderName

I have taken look at a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659869/ios9-swift-file-creating-nsfilemanager-createdirectoryatpath-with-nsurl/39157543) and have tried all methods but its still giving me the error, am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated

Comment: If the app is sandboxed the behavior is normal. You have no permission to write outside of the application container.

Comment: I'm running it on a simulator. So, you mean to say, once I export my app I will be able to do this? How should I test it now?

Comment: No, you will not. That's a rule of the sandbox.

Comment: Can you tell me where should I put my sample folder for testing?

Comment: try code signing your app and check. this will help. <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am Assuming that your app is sandboxed. So you don't have permission to write folder for location where you are trying to.

If it not intended for Sandboxed  you can disable the App Sandbox, it can be turned off by clicking on your project file > target name, selecting the capabilities tab and switching the App Sandbox off.

File System Programming Guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

App Sandbox documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html

You can also look security scoped bookmark for persistent resource access.

Documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW18

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped. I was still able to create the directories with App Sandbox on, by giving permission access to "User Selected File" from Read only to Read/Write.