# I cannot able to create directory in my file manager

Tags: ios, swift

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “subash” in the folder “tmp”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/902FE064-C3EC-42B5-A8F8-3D2923947067/tmp/subash, NSUnderlyingError=0x281e5c6f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

```swift
do {
  var mytmppath:String=FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.absoluteString+"subash"
  try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: mytmppath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

  print( FileManager.default.subpaths(atPath: FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.absoluteString))
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: From Review: Please add some description and context to you question. See: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Swift 4.0 And Swift 3.0
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162610/create-directory-in-swift-3-0

Comment: please analyse  the error @HiềnĐỗ

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659869/ios9-swift-file-creating-nsfilemanager-createdirectoryatpath-with-nsurl  , 
I found your answer in this example

Comment: @subashchandru if i am not wrong you are try to create directory in temporaryDirectory not document directory. try to use documentDirectory for create folder

Comment: how to do that please make it as an answer @chiragshah

Comment: @subashchandru follow the link which suggest by Hiền Đỗ. Checked accepted answer. or you can used Vadian answer also

Answer (score 6):

You are using the wrong API.

[`absoluteString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779984-absolutestring) is for remote URLs because the API will return also the URL scheme (e.g, `http://`, in this case `file://`).

To get a path from a file system URL you have to use [`path`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779812-path).

Nevertheless you are strongly discouraged from concatenating paths with `+`. Use always the URL related API and the dedicated path manipulation methods.

```
do {
    let defaultManager = FileManager.default
    let temporarySubURL = defaultManager.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("subash")
    try defaultManager.createDirectory(at: temporarySubURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

    print( defaultManager.subpaths(atPath: FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.path))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one using objective c

```
e NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
documentsPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:currentUser.mobileNumber];
NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryName];
NSError *error;

if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory
                               withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                attributes:nil
                                                     error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
}
```